# Using Bing Maps API to get current latitude and longitude

Tags: node.js, latitude-longitude, bing-maps

I am trying to get a person's latitude and longitude based on where they send a text message but am running into issues. I tried referring to the some Bing Maps documentation:

https://www.npmjs.com/package/geobing

```
geobing.getCoordinates('178 Laurel Brook Road, Middlefield, CT 06455',     
function (err, coordinates) {
    console.log('lat: ', coordinates.lat, 'lng: ', coordinates.lng); //    
    lat: 41.5091613 lng: -72.6943264 
});
```

I am unsure how to exactly get my current location based on where I sent the text. I am writing in node.js.

Comment: What exactly is your problem? How do you want to determine the position?

Comment: I am unsure of which methods in the Bing library will help me get my current latitude and longitude. I want to determine my position based on where I send the text message. For example, if I am in San Diego, I want the latitude and longitude to correspond to my location in San Diego.

Comment: So you want to determine the position of the device sending a message? The Bing service will not help. Either use GPS sensors on the client if you're on a mobile device, or use the client's IP address to determine a likely location.

Comment: using node.js server side it still isn't clear how they send the text message .. if is from a browser app then assuming browser supports it use navigator.geolocation.getCurrentPosition() as per http://www.w3schools.com/html/html5_geolocation.asp

Comment: And? How did you solve it?

Comment: Have you provided your Bing Maps key before making the geocoding request?